# async endpoints for swagger generated server using tornado

Tags: swagger, python-asyncio, tornado

I have generated a server using swagger editor. Then I move to using Tornado as http-server like:

```
def main():
    app = App(system_manager=system_manager, import_name=__name__,
              specification_dir='./swagger/', server='tornado')
    app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={
                'title': 'API'}, pythonic_params=True)
    app.run(port=8085)
```

Where App is:

```
class App(connexion.App):
def __init__(self, system_manager, import_name, server='tornado', **kwargs):
    super(App, self).__init__(import_name, server=server, **kwargs)
    if not issubclass(type(system_manager), SystemManager):
        raise ValueError(
            "App.init: 'system_manager' is not a subclass of 'SystemManager'")
    self.__system_manager = system_manager

def run(self, port=None, server=None, debug=None, host=None, **options):
    server_type = server or self.server
    if server_type != 'tornado':
        super(App, self).run(port=port, server=server,
                             debug=debug, host=host, **options)
        return None
    if port is not None:
        self.port = port
    elif self.port is None:
        self.port = 5000

    self.host = host or self.host or '0.0.0.0'

    if server is not None:
        self.server = server

    if debug is not None:
        self.debug = debug

    wsgi_container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(self.app)
    http_server = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/websocket/.*', WebSocket, dict(system_manager=self.__system_manager)),
        (r'^/v1/wifi(/all)*$', AsyncFallbackHandler,
         dict(fallback=wsgi_container)),
        (r'.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_container))
    ], websocket_ping_interval=5)
    http_server.listen(self.port, address=self.host)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

For some reasons I have some endpoints that are taking ~30secs to respond and because I am using `WSGIContainer` all the requests are synchronous. Which means that every request comming after those ones will be dealyed until they are done. Cite from documentation:

> WSGI is a synchronous interface, while Tornado's concurrency model is
> based on single-threaded asynchronous execution. This means that
> running a WSGI app with Tornado's WSGIContainer is less scalable than
> running the same app in a multi-threaded WSGI server like gunicorn or
> uwsgi.

I have tried to:

1. Keep using `WSGIContainer` but in a handler that will make calls async. Didn't work out. I'm getting: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'`

```
    class AsyncFallbackHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(
        self, fallback: Callable[[httputil.HTTPServerRequest], None]
    ) -> None:
        self.fallback = fallback

    async def prepare(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self.run_in_executor()
        self._finished = True
        self.on_finish()

    async def run_in_executor(self):
        loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().asyncio_loop
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            fs=[loop.run_in_executor(None, self.fallback, self.request)],
            return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
        )
```

2. Create another RequestHandler which is not using WSGIContainer. But here when the request is 404 it fails to json encode `ConnexionResponse`. Neither I can write a `ConnexionResponse` to pipe as it has to be string/bytes/dict.

```
class WifiRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # await tornado.gen.sleep(20)
        ids = self.get_arguments('ids')
        method = get_wifi
        if self.request.path.startswith('/v1/wifi/all'):
            method = get_wifi_all

        self.write(await self.run_in_executor(method, ids))
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(kwargs)
        body = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        self.write(await self.run_in_executor(update_wifi, body))
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    async def run_in_executor(self, method, *args):
        loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().asyncio_loop
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            fs=[loop.run_in_executor(None, method, args)],
            return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
        )
        result = done.pop().result()
        if type(result) is ConnexionResponse:
            return result
        enc = JSONEncoder()
        return enc.encode(result)
```

Please help me find a way to make some of my endpoints asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I made my second solution to work by unpacking the ConnexionResponse and setting the status_code. This is how it looks after fix:

```
async def run_in_executor(self, method, *args):
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().asyncio_loop
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        fs=[loop.run_in_executor(None, method, args)],
        return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
    )
    result = done.pop().result()
    if type(result) is ConnexionResponse:
        self.set_status(result.status_code)
        return result.body
    enc = JSONEncoder()
    return enc.encode(result)
```